# Why does $u_1+\cdots+u_m=0$ imply that each $u_j$ equals $0$ in Chapter 5 of Linear Algebra Done Right (Axler)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently reading Linear Algebra Done Right (Axler) and the following argument is not totally clear to me. The proof of 5.38 contains the following. [In the below $E(\lambda_j,T)$ is the eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda_j$.]

> To show that $E(\lambda_1,T)+\cdots+E(\lambda_m,T)$ is a direct sum, suppose $$u_1+\cdots+u_m=0,$$
> where each $u_j$ is in $E(\lambda,T)$. Because eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent (see 5.10), this implies that each $u_j$ equals 0.

Why can we conclude that each $u_j$ equals $0$? I’m not sure this even warrants a question since it’s probably very basic but I can’t seem to find why this is true.

Thanks for considering my question!

Edit. I’ve modified my question which was poorly (wrongly) worded.

Comment: "*Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is linearly independent and that $v_1+\dots+v_n=0$*"  Those two things can not simultaneously be true.  As such the premise being false can imply anything and everything including that the moon is made of cheese and that you are the queen of england.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that not every vector in $E(\lambda_i,T)$ is an eigenvector!  (*Edit:* Originally the post identified the $u_i$ as eigenvectors). The subspace $E(\lambda_i,T)$ consists of all vectors that are eigenvectors of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$, **plus the zero vector** (otherwise, it's not a subspace).

So the assertion is *not* that you have *eigenvectors* whose sum is equal to $0$. The assertion is that you have **vectors in the eigenspaces** whose sum is $0$.

Now, what is the definition of "$v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent"? It is:

> For any scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$, if $\alpha_1v_1+\cdots + \alpha_nv_n=\mathbf{0}$  then $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$.

Suppose you have a sum
$$u_1+\cdots +u_n=\mathbf{0},$$
and $u_i\in E(\lambda_i,T)$.

Assume some of the $u_i$ are nonzero (again, remember, they are *either* eigenvectors, or zero). Removing all the vectors that *are* equal to zero, we may then assume that they are all eigenvectors, corresponding to distinct eigenvalues. But that means that $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ are linearly independent. But then we have
$$1u_1 + \cdots + 1u_n = u_1+\cdots+u_n = \mathbf{0},$$
because we are assuming that the sum is equal to $\mathbf{0}$. Because $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ are linearly independent, this means that all scalars must be equal to $0$. But the scalars are $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=1$. So $1=0$... which is a contradiction.

Where did the contradiction come from? From the assumption that some of the $u_i$ were nonzero. Thus, it must be the case that all $u_i$ are equal to $\mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot to add some scalars to your equation, if the sum were to be zero ($1v_1 + \dots +1v_n = 0$), then the definition of linear independence implies $1=0$, wich can never happen.